# How do I switch between active docker-machines on OSX?

Tags: macos, docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

Within MacOS, I have created 2 docker machines, say, dev1 and dev2. 
In one terminal running `$docker-machine active` shows dev1 as an active docker-machine and in the other, dev2. Now I want to switch to dev2 in the 1st terminal (without stopping/removing etc. dev1) so that I'll have dev2 in both.

How do I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

run command in your terminal `eval $(docker-machine env [machine-name])`
Run `docker-machine ls` to get available machines list

Answer (score 1):

So I have been researching on this for some time and what I found is that I have to run `$eval "$(docker-machine env dev2)"` in Terminal 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `docker-machine env` command. For example:

```
$ eval "$(docker-machine env <machine-name>)"
```

This will set environment variables that the Docker client will read which specify the TLS settings. Note that you will need to do that every time you open a new tab or restart your machine.

To see what will be set, run `docker-machine env`

```
$ docker-machine env <machine-name>
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://172.16.62.130:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/<your username>/.docker/machine/machines/dev"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="dev"
```